# Not getting http GET Response

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

I Created a text view that is getting populated with the get data and I have added a sample json response url in the code. But I am not getting HTTP GET Response.

My Code is following:

```
allNotifications = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.getresponse);
    allNotifications.setText("hello");
    try {
        //URL url = new URL("http://192.168.2.5:5213/controller/moodoff/notifications/9681578989");
        URL url = new URL("http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        int data = isr.read();
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder("");
        if(data!=-1){
            response.append((char)data);
            data = isr.read();
        }
        allNotifications.setText("Hi:"+response.toString());
    }catch(Exception ee){allNotifications.setText(ee.getMessage());ee.printStackTrace();}
```

The Log is:

```
 09-29 12:45:21.826 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:45:22.748 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:45:22.750 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:45:22.750 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:45:22.750 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 192
09-29 12:45:34.125 895-943/? E/WifiStateMachine: syncGetLinkLayerStats called, stack: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@c8a7cd0
09-29 12:45:34.324 23660-23660/? E/WifiManager: mWifiServiceMessenger == null
09-29 12:45:34.753 23660-23660/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
09-29 12:45:34.830 10385-10431/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f7b991a00 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x7f7bafe9a0 arg=0x0
09-29 12:45:34.830 10385-10431/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f7b991a00 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
09-29 12:45:35.346 23660-23726/? E/YouTube: Invalid playback type; playback will not start.
09-29 12:45:35.614 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:45:36.590 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:45:36.592 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:45:36.592 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:45:36.592 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 193
09-29 12:45:36.810 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:45:37.741 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:45:37.743 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:45:37.744 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:45:37.744 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 194
09-29 12:45:39.534 10385-10480/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f4e067380 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x7f7a4fe220 arg=0x0
09-29 12:45:39.534 10385-10480/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f4e067380 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_ECDSA
09-29 12:45:43.009 895-1422/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:45:43.010 895-1422/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:45:43.011 895-1422/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000)m, error(0), index(2)
09-29 12:45:43.026 2131-2246/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
09-29 12:45:43.043 2131-2246/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
09-29 12:45:46.772 895-5585/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:45:47.920 3154-3154/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:45:47.923 3154-3154/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:45:47.927 3154-3154/? E/SIMInfo: SimStatusChangeReceiver, ss=null
09-29 12:45:47.981 3154-23992/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:45:47.983 3154-23992/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:45:47.998 3154-23992/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:45:48.000 3154-23992/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:45:49.641 3154-3154/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:45:49.642 3154-3154/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:45:49.644 3154-3154/? E/SIMInfo: SimStatusChangeReceiver, ss=null
09-29 12:45:49.690 3154-24018/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:45:49.693 3154-24018/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:45:49.702 3154-24018/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:45:49.704 3154-24018/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:45:51.845 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:45:52.726 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:45:52.732 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:45:52.732 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:45:52.733 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 195
09-29 12:45:54.294 19176-19209/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f7b57b300 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x7f7b8b43a0 arg=0x0
09-29 12:45:54.294 19176-19209/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f7b57b300 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
09-29 12:46:06.832 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:46:07.783 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:46:07.785 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:46:07.785 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:46:07.785 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 196
09-29 12:46:14.900 895-906/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:46:14.902 895-906/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:46:14.902 895-906/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000)m, error(0), index(2)
09-29 12:46:15.824 895-1614/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:46:21.846 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:46:22.943 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:46:22.946 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:46:22.946 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:46:22.946 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 197
09-29 12:46:36.857 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:46:37.873 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:46:37.876 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:46:37.876 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:46:37.876 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 198
09-29 12:46:43.929 895-905/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:46:43.930 895-905/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:46:43.931 895-905/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000)m, error(0), index(2)
09-29 12:46:44.873 895-3286/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:46:51.888 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:46:52.957 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:46:52.960 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:46:52.960 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:46:52.960 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 199
09-29 12:47:06.901 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:47:07.999 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:47:08.002 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:47:08.002 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:47:08.002 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 200
09-29 12:47:12.990 895-1559/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:47:12.991 895-1559/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:47:12.991 895-1559/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000)m, error(0), index(2)
09-29 12:47:13.912 895-906/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:47:21.908 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:47:22.953 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:47:22.955 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:47:22.956 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:47:22.956 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 201
09-29 12:47:36.909 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:47:38.062 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:47:38.067 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:47:38.067 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:47:38.067 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 202
09-29 12:47:43.061 895-905/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:47:43.063 895-905/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:47:43.063 895-905/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000)m, error(0), index(2)
09-29 12:47:43.080 2131-2246/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
09-29 12:47:43.096 2131-2246/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
09-29 12:47:43.985 895-1613/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:47:46.508 10385-10428/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f727c4580 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x7f7bdbe2f0 arg=0x0
09-29 12:47:46.508 10385-10428/? E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f727c4580 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
09-29 12:47:51.945 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:47:52.916 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:47:52.919 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:47:52.919 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:47:52.919 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 203
09-29 12:48:06.932 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:48:07.925 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:48:07.929 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:48:07.929 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:48:07.930 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 204
09-29 12:48:12.086 895-905/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:48:12.092 895-905/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:48:12.092 895-905/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000)m, error(0), index(2)
09-29 12:48:13.013 895-1422/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:48:21.945 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:48:22.923 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:48:22.925 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:48:22.925 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:48:22.925 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 205
09-29 12:48:36.951 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:48:38.039 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:48:38.044 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:48:38.044 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:48:38.044 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 206
09-29 12:48:41.139 895-1558/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:48:41.140 895-1558/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:48:41.140 895-1558/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000)m, error(0), index(2)
09-29 12:48:42.070 895-1559/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:48:51.986 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:48:52.937 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:48:52.940 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:48:52.940 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:48:52.940 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 207
09-29 12:49:06.975 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:49:07.878 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:49:07.880 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:49:07.880 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:49:07.880 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 208
09-29 12:49:10.179 895-5661/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:49:10.181 895-5661/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:49:10.181 895-5661/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000)m, error(0), index(2)
09-29 12:49:11.103 895-3565/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:49:22.010 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:49:22.956 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:49:22.959 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:49:22.959 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:49:22.959 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 209
09-29 12:49:37.003 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:49:37.910 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:49:37.914 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:49:37.914 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:49:37.915 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 210
09-29 12:49:43.123 895-905/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:49:43.125 895-905/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:49:43.125 895-905/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000)m, error(0), index(2)
09-29 12:49:43.143 2131-2246/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
09-29 12:49:43.160 2131-2246/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
09-29 12:49:43.405 2531-27476/? E/memtrack_graphic: graphic_memtrack_get_memory error to open /sys/kernel/debug/ion/clients/2531: Permission denied
09-29 12:49:46.886 895-1501/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:49:52.037 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:49:53.037 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:49:53.040 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:49:53.041 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:49:53.041 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 211
09-29 12:50:07.050 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:50:08.044 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:50:08.047 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:50:08.047 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:50:08.047 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 212
09-29 12:50:15.084 895-3565/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:50:15.086 895-3565/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:50:15.086 895-3565/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000)m, error(0), index(2)
09-29 12:50:16.011 895-5661/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:50:22.047 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:50:23.081 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:50:23.083 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:50:23.084 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:50:23.084 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 213
09-29 12:50:37.053 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:50:38.013 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:50:38.017 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:50:38.017 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:50:38.017 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 214
09-29 12:50:44.095 895-1614/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:50:44.097 895-1614/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:50:44.097 895-1614/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000)m, error(0), index(2)
09-29 12:50:45.081 895-5663/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:50:52.080 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:50:53.018 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:50:53.021 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:50:53.021 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:50:53.021 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 215
09-29 12:51:07.074 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:51:07.967 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:51:07.970 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:51:07.970 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:51:07.970 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 216
09-29 12:51:13.187 895-5661/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:51:13.189 895-5661/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:51:13.189 895-5661/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000)m, error(0), index(2)
09-29 12:51:14.106 895-905/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:51:22.107 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:51:23.054 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:51:23.056 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:51:23.056 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:51:23.057 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 217
09-29 12:51:33.052 29082-29100/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
09-29 12:51:37.102 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:51:38.019 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:51:38.021 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:51:38.021 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:51:38.021 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 218
09-29 12:51:44.157 895-3286/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:51:44.158 895-3286/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:51:44.158 895-3286/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000)m, error(0), index(2)
09-29 12:51:44.174 2131-2246/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
09-29 12:51:44.190 2131-2246/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
09-29 12:51:45.084 895-5663/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:51:46.091 3154-3154/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:51:46.092 3154-3154/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:51:46.094 3154-3154/? E/SIMInfo: SimStatusChangeReceiver, ss=null
09-29 12:51:46.120 3154-29330/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:51:46.121 3154-29330/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:51:46.129 3154-29330/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:51:46.130 3154-29330/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:51:49.048 3154-3154/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:51:49.049 3154-3154/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:51:49.051 3154-3154/? E/SIMInfo: SimStatusChangeReceiver, ss=null
09-29 12:51:49.082 3154-29373/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:51:49.083 3154-29373/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:51:49.090 3154-29373/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:51:49.091 3154-29373/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:51:50.761 3154-3154/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:51:50.764 3154-3154/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:51:50.767 3154-3154/? E/SIMInfo: SimStatusChangeReceiver, ss=null
09-29 12:51:50.801 3154-29399/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:51:50.802 3154-29399/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:51:50.808 3154-29399/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:51:50.809 3154-29399/? E/SIMInfo: info.mWapPush init error, not support in FW.
09-29 12:51:52.122 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:51:53.148 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:51:53.151 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:51:53.151 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:51:53.151 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 219
09-29 12:52:07.147 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:52:07.618 21240-21240/com.moodoff E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
09-29 12:52:07.800 19622-19622/? E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
09-29 12:52:08.191 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:52:08.193 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:52:08.193 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:52:08.193 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 220
09-29 12:52:13.177 895-1422/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:52:13.178 895-1422/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:52:13.178 895-1422/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000)m, error(0), index(2)
09-29 12:52:14.100 895-5663/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:52:22.148 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:52:23.299 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:52:23.313 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:52:23.313 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:52:23.313 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 221
09-29 12:52:37.151 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:52:38.184 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:52:38.202 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:52:38.202 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:52:38.202 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 222
09-29 12:52:42.196 895-3564/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:52:42.198 895-3564/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:52:42.198 895-3564/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000)m, error(0), index(2)
09-29 12:52:43.120 895-5663/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:52:52.165 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:52:53.246 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:52:53.249 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:52:53.249 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:52:53.249 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 223
09-29 12:53:07.176 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:53:08.278 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:53:08.282 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:53:08.282 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false

09-29 12:53:14.371 2131-2226/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
09-29 12:53:22.207 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:53:23.360 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:53:23.365 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:53:23.365 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:53:23.365 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 225
09-29 12:53:37.201 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:53:38.163 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:53:38.166 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:53:38.166 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:53:38.166 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 226
09-29 12:53:45.182 895-3565/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:53:45.183 895-3565/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:53:45.184 895-3565/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000)m, error(0), index(2)
09-29 12:53:45.246 2131-2246/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
09-29 12:53:45.266 2131-2246/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
09-29 12:53:48.946 895-1559/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
09-29 12:53:52.235 895-8341/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
09-29 12:53:53.362 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore: setLastSelectedConfiguration -1
09-29 12:53:53.364 895-1191/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
09-29 12:53:53.364 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: true, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
09-29 12:53:53.364 895-1191/? E/WifiStateMachine: mWifiOnScanCount: 227
```

Comment: you getting exception?

Comment: not sure but if network I think need add async task/running thread??

Comment: put this code in thread

Comment: no exception as such.

Comment: Please add more debug information, what is happening? And what is what you expect to be happening? As you say a textview is getting populated but not getting a GET response?

Comment: Two things you should double check, 1. make sure you are connected to internet and 2. make sure you have the correct internet permission in the manifest

Comment: Thanks to all of you. The data is being fetched and is being shown in CONSOLE, but there is an issue. When I am using the textview to see the same response, i am getting this in the textview, saying:   ONLY THE ORIGINAL THREAD THAT CREATED A VIEW HIERARCHY CAN TOUCH ITS VIEWS.

Answer (score 1):

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            URL url = new URL("http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            int data = isr.read();
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder("");
            if(data!=-1){
                 response.append((char)data);
                 data = isr.read();
             }
        // code below need put back to main thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        allNotifications.setText("Hi:"+response.toString());
                    }
                });

                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: allNotifications.setText("Hi:"+response.toString()); Should be on the UIThread otherwise it will go wrong :)

Comment: I miss press button haha

Comment: Thank You. I think this could be the solution to the current issue i am stuck on. Can you let me know how to get the UI thread as i have not spawned any new thread. Do i need to do Thread.currentThread and how?

Comment: Suppose it will be work if add into the runOnUiThread.if cannot then you may try out the async task. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //URL url = new URL("http://192.168.2.5:5213/controller/moodoff/notifications/9681578989");
                    URL url = new URL("http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two");
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                    int data = isr.read();
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder("");
                    if(data!=-1){
                        response.append((char)data);
                        data = isr.read();
                    }
                    Log.i("TAG","Response:="+response.toString());
                    //allNotifications.setText("Hi:"+response.toString());
                }catch(Exception ee){allNotifications.setText(ee.getMessage());ee.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }).start();
```

try this code. it will work .

Comment: dipali: Thank you. I have used this code for editing, it is printing the data in console using Log.i, but not in the textview. What am i getting? I have added a comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to call `urlConnection.connect()` before calling `getInputStream()`